# linq lambda expression and '&' operator

Tags: c#, linq

I'm working on a ASP.NET MVC (an older version) application and I have a form where students are assigned an adviser based on a major code AND by alpha of a student's last name.

I am trying to implement the below code but it is showing red scribbles to `&` operator:

> Error: operator '&' cannot be applied to operands of type '`System.Linq.IQueryable<Appointments.Models.MajorAdviserStudentAssignmentByAlpha>`' and 'lambda expression' and 'lambda expression'

```
var majorAssignmentByAlpha = FindAllMajorAdviserStudentAssignmentByAlphas()
    .Where(
           a => a.MajorString == student.StudentMajor) &
           (a => ((String.Compare(student.StudentLastName, a.AlphaStart) >= 0) &
                 (String.Compare(student.StudentLastName, a.AlphaEnd) <= 0))
    .FirstOrDefault());

if (majorAssignmentByAlpha != null)
    return majorAssignmentByAlpha.Adviser;
```

I would appreciate any help to understand what's wrong here.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: The answers below saying that `&` is the bitwise and operation and `&&` is the logical are wrong.  `&` can be either bitwise or logical but, if logical, always executed both sides.  `&&` skips the right half if the left half is false.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would like to add a correction here: actually both `&&` *and* `&` **are** boolean AND operators in C# (when used with `bool`). However the former will do a [short-circuit evaluation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2a723cdk%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

Consider `A && B`, if `A` is `false` then `B` will not be evaluated since the result will be `false` no matter what is the truthness of `B`.

And for the error you are getting, probably that's because your `&` operator is comparing a boolean expression and a lambda expression (function). Try this

```
MajorAdviserStudentAssignmentByAlpha majorAssignmentByAlpha = FindAllMajorAdviserStudentAssignmentByAlphas().FirstOrDefault(
        a => a.MajorString == student.StudentMajor & String.Compare(student.StudentLastName, a.AlphaStart) >= 0 &
             String.Compare(student.StudentLastName, a.AlphaEnd) <= 0);

    if (majorAssignmentByAlpha != null)
        return majorAssignmentByAlpha.Adviser;
```

Comment: Consider flipping the position of the answer and the supplemental note.

Comment: Thanks for the formatting edit :)

Comment: @rexcfnghk: Thank you! I used your code just slightly editing the parentheses after the 'a.AlphaEnd', like: 

MajorAdviserStudentAssignmentByAlpha majorAssignmentByAlpha = FindAllMajorAdviserStudentAssignmentByAlphas().FirstOrDefault(
             a => a.MajorString == student.StudentMajor & String.Compare(student.StudentLastName, a.AlphaStart) >= 0 &
             String.Compare(student.StudentLastName, a.AlphaEnd) <= 0);

            if (majorAssignmentByAlpha != null)
                return majorAssignmentByAlpha.Adviser;
Hope it's correct, at least it doesn't give me an error message.

Comment: ah yes...slight typo. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you! Sorry I didn't format my comments :(
Do you know why i was getting red scribbles to 'FirstOrDefault()' when I was trying to implement the 'TheEvilPenguin's' code which is the last one in this discussion? (Error: 'bool' does not contain a definition for 'FirstOrDefault' and no extension method 'FirstOrDefault' accepting a first argument of the type 'bool' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference").

Comment: It's because of your parentheses. `FirstOrDefault()` is an extension method of `IEnumerable<>` but not `bool`. You are calling `FirstOrDefault()` with `((String.Compare(student.StudentLastName, a.AlphaStart) >= 0) & (String.Compare(student.StudentLastName, a.AlphaEnd) <= 0))` which is of type `bool`. **Use your IDE to check your parentheses**

Answer (score 1):

That's because the operator that you're looking it's `&&`. Refactor your Linq expresssion like this

```
MajorAdviserStudentAssignmentByAlpha majorAssignmentByAlpha = FindAllMajorAdviserStudentAssignmentByAlphas().Where(
        a => a.MajorString == student.StudentMajor) &&
        (a => ((String.Compare(student.StudentLastName, a.AlphaStart) >= 0) &&
             (String.Compare(student.StudentLastName, a.AlphaEnd) <= 0)).FirstOrDefault());

    if (majorAssignmentByAlpha != null)
        return majorAssignmentByAlpha.Adviser;
```

Comment: See my comments above.  `&` can be either logical or bitwise.

Comment: Actually I agreed with you comment, but I think that in this scenario he's looking for this operator

Comment: Sorry, I assumed that was what you meant as this code won't compile for me - it's still trying to logical-and a bool and a lambda.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're added too many parentheses.  Try this:

```
MajorAdviserStudentAssignmentByAlpha majorAssignmentByAlpha = FindAllMajorAdviserStudentAssignmentByAlphas().Where(
            a => a.MajorString == student.StudentMajor &&
                 String.Compare(student.StudentLastName, a.AlphaStart >= 0) &
                 String.Compare(student.StudentLastName, a.AlphaEnd <= 0)).FirstOrDefault();

if (majorAssignmentByAlpha != null)
    return majorAssignmentByAlpha.Adviser;
```

.Where() takes a single expression returning `bool`.  You are trying to and together two different expressions.  If you remove the close parentheses before the `&&`, the open parentheses after and the second `a =>`, you're anding two boolean statements, which works.

Comment: For some reason when I was trying to implement your code it was showing red scribbles to 'FirstOrDefault()'. (Error: 'bool' does not contain a definition for 'FirstOrDefault' and no extension method 'FirstOrDefault' accepting a first argument of the type 'bool' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference").
Sorry for asking you about this ed scribbles to 'FirstOrDefault'

Comment: @Gregg Fixed.  Sorry, it worked in LINQPad but I must have made a mistake when copying it out.  I had mismatched parentheses

Answer (score -1):

I think you meant to use `&&` for the logical AND operation.

`FirstOrDefault()` also takes a `Func<T, bool>` so you could do:

```
var majorAssignmentByAlpha = FindAllMajorAdviserStudentAssignmentByAlphas().FirstOrDefault(
            a => a.MajorString == student.StudentMajor &&
            (a => ((String.Compare(student.StudentLastName, a.AlphaStart) >= 0) &&
                 (String.Compare(student.StudentLastName, a.AlphaEnd) <= 0));
```

Comment: While `&&` is probably what should be used here, it will only shortcut evaluating the second operand.  `&` can be either bitwise or logical.

Comment: @TheEvilPenguin: While you are correct, I answered in the context of the OP's question, which is why I did not bother to mention that.

Comment: Sorry, as the code still doesn't compile for me I made an assumption.